# Laravel - login authentication application with vue api error 405

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api, vue.js

I have laravel api in my site and i keep getting error 405. It's a very simple login/register app.
Here is my login component:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center items-center pt-56">
       <div class="flex flex-wrap max-w-xl">
           <div class="p-2 text-2xl text-gray-800 font-semibold"><h1>Login to your account</h1></div>
           <div class="p-2 w-full">
               <label for="email">Your e-mail</label>
               <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Email" type="email" v-model="form.email">
           </div>
           <div class="p-2 w-full">
               <label for="password">Password</label>
               <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Password" type="password" v-model="form.password" name="password">
           </div>
           <div class="p-2 w-full mt-4">
               <button @click.prevent="loginUser" type="submit" class="flex text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">Login</button>
           </div>
       </div> 
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data(){
       return{
           form:{
               email: '',
               password: ''
           },
           errors: []
       }
   },
   methods:{
        loginUser(){
            this.axios.post('api/login', this.form).then(() =>{
                this.$router.push({ name: "ProductIndex"}); 
            }).catch((error) =>{
        this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
                console.log(error);
           })
        }
   }
}
</script>
```

Here is my register component:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center items-center pt-56">
      <div class="flex flex-wrap max-w-xl">
          <div class="p-2 text-2xl text-gray-800 font-semibold"><h1>Register an account</h1></div>
          <div class="p-2 w-full">
              <label class="w-full" for="name">Name</label>
              <!-- <span class="w-full text-red-500" v-if="errors.this.name">{{errors.this.name[0]}}</span> -->
              <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Name" type="text" v-model="form.name" >
          </div>
          <div class="p-2 w-full">
              <label for="email">Your e-mail</label>
              <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Email" type="email" v-model="form.email">
          </div>
          <div class="p-2 w-full">
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Password" type="password" v-model="form.password" name="password">
          </div>
          <div class="p-2 w-full">
              <label for="confirm_password">Confirm Password</label>
              <input class="w-full bg-gray-100 rounded border border-gray-400 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 text-base px-4 py-2" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" v-model="form.password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation">
          </div>
          <div class="p-2 w-full mt-4">
              <button @click.prevent="saveForm" type="submit" class="flex text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0 py-2 px-8 focus:outline-none hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded text-lg">Register</button>
          </div>
      </div> 
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data(){
      return{
          form:{
              name: '',
              email: '',
              password:'',
              password_confirmation:''
          },
          errors:[]
      }
  },
  methods:{
      saveForm(){
          this.axios.post('api/register', this.form).then(() =>{
              console.log('saved');
          }).catch((error) =>{
              this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
              console.log(error);
          })
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is my LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required']
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))){
            return response()->json(Auth::user(), 200);
        }
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'email' =>['The provided credentials are incorect.']
        ]);
    }
    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
    }
}
```

Here is my RegisterController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users'],
            'password' =>['required', 'min:6', 'confirmed']
        ]);

        User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
        ]);
    }
}
```

and my api.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/
//this is for my product list crud and it is working perfectly fine
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
    Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
});
//
Route::post('/register', 'App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController@register');
Route::post('login', '\App\Http\Controllers\LoginController@login');
```

Error message:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/api/login 405 (Method Not Allowed)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:3455
xhrAdapter @ app.js:3281
dispatchRequest @ app.js:3986
request @ app.js:3757
Axios.<computed> @ app.js:3789
wrap @ app.js:4401
loginUser @ app.js:5379
click @ app.js:29088
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:36783
invoker @ app.js:34603
original_1._wrapper @ app.js:41055
```

Im using laravel 8 and vue 2.6.12, I have no idea why I'm getting this error, I checked my php artisan route:list and everything looks fine.

Comment: You run your laravel by php artisan serve? why the endpoint has /accounts?

Comment: Yes i run it by php artisan serve, I have my login components in componets/accounts folder